# Get statistics of screen resolution of the device in play store console

Tags: android, google-play

I want to check the resolution of the device on which my app is installed or uninstalled for example(640 dp by 360 dp) in the play store statistics.I tried searching for such statistics but cant find it.
Is the any other service like firebase which report such statistics?

Answer (score -2):

In the Google Play console you can see information about different device types in the "Device catalogue" section at the side. But as far as I know there is no service that joins this information with your install statistics.

Comment: The Device catalogue give information about compatibles devices, not about which is the most used for your app